std::void_t vs customize function in SFINAE usage
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct CheckX
{
    using TypeOfX = decltype(T::x);
    using Value = void;
};

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    int x;
};

template <typename T , typename = void>
struct Res
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

// template <typename T>
// struct Res<T , std::void_t<decltype(T::x)>>
// {
//     static constexpr bool value = true;
// };

template <typename T>
struct Res<T , typename CheckX<T>::Value>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Res<B>::value << '\n'; 
    std::cout << Res<A>::value << '\n'; 
}

These is the code that I want to implement a checker which check if a member x exist in a struct.
I notice that the usage of the customize CheckX result in a compilation fail while std library std::void_t will do the work.
What I am missing here ?

look at how void_t is implemented: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

Always post complete error along with your question.

The problem is that the given using declaration inside CheckX is not in the immediate context which is the only place where/when SFINAE will work.
Solution
Just put the using declaration in the immediate context by changing the using declaration to a alias template as shown below:
template <typename T>
struct CheckX
{
    template<typename U = T>
    using TypeOfX = decltype(U::x);
    using Value = void;
};

Program works now.

See also What is immediate context in SFINAE which explains the basics and my answer gives a workaround.

@wohlstad Actually understanding the real problem(which is that this is not in immediate context) and then being able to find/see/write a workaround will make OP/readers really learn the concept. That is the aim of any post on SO. So as long as the answer explains the technical reason for the second snippet to fail, adding a workaround is acceptable and appreciated.

@wohlstad " don't think the OP really needs this workaround..." I disagree. Writing a workaround is the whole reason for writing  CheckX in the first place. They want to undersand the working and the error so having a workaround specially one which corrects their mistake is good.

It's OK to disagree. My understanding was that the OP knows how to solve the problem elegantly with std::void_t, but they were just curious why the version with CheckX doesn't work, which both our answers explain.

@wohlstad Also this is not a workaround but a fix to the their already posted implementation which will make them understand the problem in a better way. Knowing the problem and then being able to fix it is part of learning the concept.

The 1st version (with void_t) works exactly as you expect:
For class A, std::void_t<decltype(T::x)> results in a substitution failure (due to the missing A::x) when this Res is considered.
This is classic SFINAE.
Therefore this version of Res is discarded, leaving us with the default Res with value = false.
The 2nd version (with CheckX<T>) does not even get to the SFINAE phase for Res:
In order to check CheckX<T>::Value first CheckX<T> is instantiated. As a part of it using TypeOfX = decltype(T::x) is parsed, and since A does not contain x, decltype(T::x) triggers an error (e.g. on MSVC: error C2039: 'x': is not a member of 'A'.
Parsing this using declaration of A is not a part of SFINAE for Res (it is done in a prelimilary stage, and not in the immediate context).
Note that this kind of scenario is the exact purpose of std::void_t (since C++17):

Utility metafunction that maps a sequence of any types to the type
void. This metafunction is a convenient way to leverage SFINAE prior
to C++20's concepts, in particular for conditionally removing
functions from the candidate set based on whether an expression is
valid in the unevaluated context (such as operand to decltype
expression), allowing to exist separate function overloads or
specializations based on supported operations.

(emphasis is mine)
Also see the example for struct has_type_member in that cppreference.com page.

@Alan I thought the workaround was not really relevant. I didn't critisize anything related to the term "immediate context". I think there is no need to be vindictive here.
